# My site "integration" with portal is not working.

Tags: user-profile-service, my-site, publishing, service-application, autospinstaller

I am using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, on premise.

I have just finished installing SharePoint in a farm with 4 SharePoint servers: 2 front-end and 2 application (back-end) servers. I installed SharePoint with AutoSpInstaller and also provisioned 2 web applications: Portal (publishing) and My Site.

On the Portal web application there is no "about me" on the drop down menu when clicking on my user name, on on the far right, which leads to the users my site. I am missing a search box as well.

[image: As can be seen in this picture, "About me" is missing]

I am also not getting any newsfeed box on the my site.

The User Profile Service Application and the Search Service Applications are successfully provisioned. I don't understand why these things out of the box are not working. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How do you know your services are provisioned and working correctly? Check your search crawler for content and test accessing it. Make sure nothing is being logged in ULS that you might be missing.
2. Check permissions on services, and with the User Profile Service, double check your entire install, including all service account permissions.
3. Check the proxies - if your services are deployed but the proxies are not added to the default proxy group or custom proxy group if you are using it than the web application can not use the service.

Comment: Could you please tell a little about how to check point number 3 here?

Comment: Reprovisioning the User Profile Service Application, without using the AutoSpInstaller, did the trick for me. Thanks for the input mate.

Comment: You also need to activate the Farm-level Feature: Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls

Answer (score 1):

Installing with AutoSpiNStaller does not mean that everything configured( i am not big fan of auto installer, it let me down all the time).

You have to make sure couple of things...as Jesus mentioned...couple more.

- check if both search and UPA service created, services running,
- UPA sync connection created and can you run a full sync
- can you run a search crawl.
- do you have your mysite web app?
- Make sure the Distributed cache is up and running.
- also check from central admin > monitor > review health rule....if they report anything

Comment: Hi Waqas. 

I have checked it all. I can create My Site, the synch service is running. No errors in health analyzer, event log or ULS with regards to search and user profile. Crawl is working.

I have the same issue even on my dev environment, where everything is green.

Comment: Everything was running, but I the problems where fixed when I re provisioned the UPS without using the AutoSpInstaller. So, I agree with you, it also lets me down all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the Farm-level Feature: `Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls`

Once that feature is enabled, the "About Me" will replace "My Settings" in the dropdown under your Username.